# How to edit pandas dataframe to remove lowercase words but keep uppercase ones?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I created by souping Indeed. After some cleaning I still have my job title field looking like:

'active visited hover focus focus-visible after Business Analyst, Commercial Systems'

I've been trying to edit this into just saying "Business Analyst, Commercial Systems" so I figured I'd try to remove all the words that start with lower case letters.

`df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace(r'^[a-z]', ' ')`

This didn't do anything as far as I can tell. I then tried this:

`df = df[df.Title.str[0].str.isupper()`

But that just removed the entire thing row altogether. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Title = df.Title.apply(
    lambda s: ' '.join([w for w in s.split() if w.istitle()])
)
```

Comment: Applying this to the dataframe would look like this

`df.loc[:,'Title'] = df['Title'].apply(lambda title: ' '.join([w for w in title.split() if w.istitle()]))`